# special characters not showing on page

Tags: html

I have meta tag as given below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"/>
<meta name="keywords"  Content="â€œSAT Courseâ€ â€œSAT examâ€ â€œSAT Prepâ€ â€œSAT Preparation Courseâ€" />
<meta name="description"  Content="Take Kaplanâ€™s SAT preparation course. We use proven score raising strategies and give you access to 4 practice tests so you can take the test with confidence." />
<meta name="copyright"  Content="Copyright Kaplan Test Prep and Admissions 2008" />
<meta name="Content-language"  Content="en-uk" />
<meta name="Distribution"  Content="global" />
<meta id="tcm" name="TMCID" Content="tcm:55-7918-64"></meta>
```

it was working fine but after some changes it start behaving differently. it is not showing special character properly some extra text is added on the page.

I have tried using charset='utf-8'.

Please suggest! what can be reason behind this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character set you have used to save the HTML in does not match the character set the browser thinks is being used. [Check your editor](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-setting-encoding-in-applications) to find out what you are really using.

I recommend setting it to UTF-8. This is a well supported encoding that supports just about any character you are likely to use, along with a large number that you aren't.

Note that the encoding you specify using meta tags does not override any encoding specified in real HTTP headers sent by your webserver. See http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset for advice on how to change it.

As an aside, if you mean the language is "British English" then you want "en-gb" not "en-uk".

Comment: can you please more clarify with some examples

Comment: The links include bucket loads of examples. There seems little point in providing more until you explain why those are inadequate.

Comment: So either the previous and live versions send different content-type headers or the data is being changed by the CMS (possibly as it gets pushed through the database). Fix you (unspecified) CMS.

Comment: everything seems fine only problem it that my pound sign is appearing like this Â£225, a special character is coming before my pound sign.

Comment: Something is changing the encoding of your data, or otherwise corrupting it.